# Incluir jQuery fora do diretório Root

Tags: html, jquery, diretório

Possuo os seguintes diretórios:

- Dev

  - libs

    - jquery.js
  - Projetos (Root)

    - index.html

No meu index.html, estou tentando utilizar o jquery da seguinte forma:

```
<script src="../libs/jquery.js"></script>
```

Entretanto, o mesmo não funciona. É como se o '../' fosse ignorado.
Como posso incluir o jquery sendo que ele está fora do diretório root? Pois pretendo utilizar um único jquery centralizado em um só lugar.

Comment: Vc está colocando "../libs/jquery.js" ? Reparou se todas as letras do caminho está em caixa alta/baixa como nos nomes das Pastas

Comment: Já conferiu na aba Network do Chrome DevTools se ele está mostrnado algum erro? Ou no console está aparecendo algum erro?

Comment: No console: GET http://localhost/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o root da sua aplicação está no nível de `Projetos`, você não pode voltar um diretório acima dele.

**Opção 1:**

Você simplesmente copia a sua pasta pasta lib para dentro de projetos

```
<script src="/libs/jquery.js"></script>
```

**Opção 2:**

Você precisaria mudar o mapeamento para `Dev` mas o seu endereço ficaria `localhost/projetos/index.html`.

**Opção 3:**

Você configura um outro site para servir os seus arquivos estáticos e os carrega a partir como se fosse uma CDN externa

```
<script src="//localhost:8080/libs/jquery.js"></script>
```

**Opção 4:**

Utilizar alguma ferramenta para gerenciar as suas dependencias e gerar pacotes de distribuição para elas em um diretório `dist` dentro do nível do seu root, no caso `Projetos`. Isso permitiria inclusive você compactar e ou minificar esses arquivos estáticos. No entanto você vai precisar estudar e escolher a que achar melhor para você, recomendo: [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/pt-br/), ou [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) ou [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) ou [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/)